# Dirty mouse of dried cream

Tags: cleaning, technology, plastics

I have a gaming mouse and many times when use it, it gets dirtier and dirtier due to the moisturising cream on my hands where they stick onto the edges and I have to use my fingernails to scrape some off. Now I believe some of the dried cream is inside the mouse itself. I also cannot take apart a razer mouse.

Any way to prevent this and get rid of the cream stuck inside the mouse? I also have to put cream on my hands or they will get dry.

Comment: Could you wear a thin glove? Either something thin and breathable (cloth glove) or something non-porous (latex glove).

Comment: @goodguy5 well there goes the grip...

Comment: Then go back to the latex glove. Latex grips a mouse.

Comment: Replace mouse if required.  If you are handy with a small screwdriver you can remove screws (usually under labels) and pry the mouse open. Remove the covers and chuck them in with your dishes.  Let them dry well and reassemble mouse, all good for 6 months again.

Comment: @KalleMP Could work, except that raser sticks their pads on top of the screw holes.

Comment: Googling for 2 minutes found the following to remove one more excuse.  -  http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-accessories/razer-mousefeet

Answer (score 2):

Same as any other electronics.

Buy some low percentage rubbing alcohol, 70% or so, and soak the whole thing for about 20 minutes. Rubbing alcohol is not conductive.

Buy a gallon of distilled water. Soak and swish around in the water. Distilled water is not conductive - it's the dissolved solids and minerals in tap water that make it conduct.

Dry it out. Put it in a bag with rice and point a lamp at it so it gets warm without melting anything and leave it there for a day or so.

Comment: How about the mechanical parts such as the switches? Wouldn't the water get stuck in them?

Comment: Not a good idea for optics either.

Comment: @Bradman175 no this is what the lamp and rice or silica packets are for - all of the water evaporates because of the warmth. Gas does not get stuck in mechanical parts.

Comment: @KalleMP good point about the optics. Better to just wipe down the top and rinse.

Answer (score 0):

I get the idea of having a moisturized skin, but whenever you're gonna use your mouse wash your hands first, just to make sure you get rid off of any oily substances from the cream.

To clean the exterior of your mouse, I'd suggest isopropilic alcohol, as for the interior of your mouse, well I can't really suggest you any approach without compromising your device's integrity. I can however -as an owner of a razer mouse- suggest you to use a presentation card/piece of paper folded at least 3 times(to give it sturdiness) to clean the edges every 3-4 days if you use it daily, this will reduce the chances of any excess of cream getting stuck inside your mouse.

NOTE: There are also creams that are less oily while providing the same level of moisturizing effect.So if washing your hands before gaming isn't an option, you can always just find the perfect moisturizer for your needs.